# Dynamic Linq Conditional Select

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, dynamic-linq

```
var Data = from z in initialData
           select new
           {
              z.ID,
              z.Value = (z.Col1 != null)? z.Col1 : z.Col2
           };
```

How can I convert this query to a dynamic linq expression? Is this even possible?

Comment: I do not think that it is possible, because the compiler creates an anonymous class for this query.

Comment: The code can be improved to z.Value = z.Col1 ?? z.Col2

Comment: What you have is not even possible, you will get: 'Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.'

Comment: i'm confused, which part do you need it to be dynamic?

Comment: @Juvil I need this behaviour in a complicated context.

Comment: Linq-to-Sql, linq-to-entites, ... ?

Comment: linq-to-entities preferably. I am not sure it would matter though.

Comment: Well, that means you could use entity SQL to build a query string dynamically. (As was suggested below).

Answer (score 0):

try this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303.aspx

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities context =
    new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    // Call the constructor with a query for products and the ObjectContext.
    ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery1 =
        new ObjectQuery<Product>("Products", context);

    foreach (Product result in productQuery1)
        Console.WriteLine("Product Name: {0}", result.Name);

    string queryString =
        @"SELECT VALUE product FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Products AS product";

    // Call the constructor with the specified query and the ObjectContext.
    ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery2 =
        new ObjectQuery<Product>(queryString, context);

    foreach (Product result in productQuery2)
        Console.WriteLine("Product Name: {0}", result.Name);

    // Call the constructor with the specified query, the ObjectContext,  // and the NoTracking merge option.
    ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery3 =
        new ObjectQuery<Product>(queryString,
            context, MergeOption.NoTracking);

    foreach (Product result in productQuery3)
        Console.WriteLine("Product Name: {0}", result.Name);
}
```

you might take a look at this section

```
string queryString =
    @"SELECT VALUE product FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Products AS product";

// Call the constructor with the specified query and the ObjectContext.
ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery2 =
    new ObjectQuery<Product>(queryString, context);

foreach (Product result in productQuery2)
    Console.WriteLine("Product Name: {0}", result.Name);
```

don't forget to mark it answered if it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing member names for your anonymous type.  Included in my answer:

```
var Data = initialData.Select(x => new 
                           { 
                               ID = x.ID, 
                               Value = (x.Col1 == null)? x.Col1 : x.Col2
                           });
```

EDIT:  Nevermind, misread the question.

Comment: Where the dynamic part? You basically just rewrote the statement.